Ferrite Core Losses calculate
I want to calculate the losses of a ferrite core. I don't want to rely on TDK limited charts and numbers.
Here Magnetics INC has a calculation with constant numbers which is very useful
I am looking to find such constant numbers that TDK has provided for its cores such as N87
https://www.mag-inc.com/Design/Design-Tools/Ferrite-Core-Loss-Calculator

How can I perform these equations on materials like N87 N27 etc.?
I think I can calculate the core losses for a pair of ferrite cores by having the correct a x y.

In order to use the equation in the Magnetics calculator, you would need to do a regression on the Epcos data which is a lot of work. Since you're operating at 100 kHz, the Epcos/TDK data for N87 is clearly shown in the graphs. N27, you would need to interpolate.

TDK doesn't provide the numbers you'd need for that, though it would be possible to extract them from some of the graphs. Remember, though, that almost all the metrics on a typical ferrite's datasheet are very approximate anyway due to how hard it is to precisely control them; any number you calculate should be considered as having error bars of perhaps as large as ±25%.
But you can get a general idea of how suitable a material is to operation at a specific frequency by comparing the magnitudes of μ' and μ'' given in the datasheet for that frequency; most ferrite manufacturers provide graphs of μ' and μ'' vs frequency. μ', the real part of permeability, represents the portion of energy that is stored and then later recovered. μ'', the imaginary part of permeability, represents the amount of energy that is lost. The ratio μ''/μ' is also called the loss tangent, tan δ, and is exactly equal to the ratio of real (lost) power to reactive (temporarily stored) power. The higher μ''/μ' is, the more power will be lost in the core.
This metric does not include the effects of saturation, which can dramatically increase losses at high AC field magnitudes. You want to avoid operating in saturation for this and other reasons; if you find your core is saturating, you need to use a different size core or a different material.
